# The PyDev plugin can not find python 3.4

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu, eclipse-plugin, pydev, python-3.4

I have been using eclipse 3.8+PyDev+python 3.3 on ubuntu 13. Recently I upgraded ubuntu to 14.04. It seems that ubuntu 14.04 comes with new python 3.4, so, during upgrading, the old python 3.3 is removed and new python 3.4 is installed. Then, the PyDev plugin of my eclipse can not find the python 3.3 in its original dir and an error is report, as well as many red crossings, as the image below shows.

[image]

But the installation of Python 3.4 is correct because I can import pickle or random modules without difficulty in IDLE which uses python 3.4:

[image]

I have already upgraded the PyDev to latest 3.4.1. Could you please tell me how to reconfigure Python interpreter (including how to locate it) in eclipse so that PyDev can correctly locate where the Python 3.4 is? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

OK, I have solved the problem by myself:

(1)Right click the project name, choose "Properties" in the popup menu. This will open the "Properties for" dialog box.

(2) In this box, select "PyDev-Interpreter/Grammar" item on the left panel and click the "click here to configure an interpreter not listed" link on the right.

(3) In the popup "Python Interpreters" dialog box, click "New..." button on the right of the window and type in the path to python 3.4 executable. In my system, it's `/usr/bin/python3.4`.

(4) Then click OK and wait for the eclipse to finish its configuration work. At this point the most important part of reconfiguration is done. Then move the new Python3.4 to the top, remove python 3.3 interpreter if you want, and ...

(5) Don't forget to restart eclipse. Tata ...

Some 3rd party python packages such as pymongo are still problematic. But they are not within the scope of discussion of this thread. That's it.